# Unable to distinguish between many rows of the same contact when executing the 'guide/v1/email' REST API call

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

My question relates to using the undocumented REST API Call Guide in Marketing Cloud.

`https://www.exacttargetapis.com/guide/v1/emails/{EMAIL_ID}/dataExtension/key:{EXTERNAL_KEY}/contacts/key:{KEY}/preview`

I can use this API call with no issues and have used it many times before but one use case I have identified which seems to be either a limitation or a misunderstanding in the way the API call can be used and what other optional parameters are available in this call.

Perhaps I can gain more insight from the community to help me identify if it's possible considering there is no evidence of documentation around this specific route.

My limitation I have identified when performing an API call on this route is being able to distinguish between which contact record to use in the event more than one of the same contact is available within the one Data Extension specified in the API route.

Does anyone know if it is possible to identify the primary key to use along with the contact key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out the solution after tinkering with the API call myself, you need to not reference contacts and reference the `/row` route followed by the row ID of the data extension to obtain the relevant data for the email where many contacts are present in the one data extension.

`https://www.exacttargetapis.com/guide/v1/emails/{EMAIL_ID}/dataExtension/key:{EXTERNAL_KEY}/row/{ROW_ID}/preview`